# Can I have multiple colors in a gnuplot label?

Tags: label, gnuplot

I have this graph in gnuplot:

[image]

I want to include totals for each of the three colored line graphs. One possibility is to replace the key with this:

[image]

Can I plot this with a single label that switches colors? If not then I'd have to use six labels. In that case, how do I determine the coordinates of the labels given that the widths of the strings can vary? I could use a fixed width font and do some computation based on the number of digits in each of the totals but this seems tedious.

Is there a more clever way to indicate totals in a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the textcolor inside a single label, you must use six different labels. However, there are some ways to simplify this:

- Use `left` and a negative `offset` in x-direction for the colored label, and `right` and a positive `offset` for the number, like

  ```
  set label 1 right at graph 0.5, char 1 "FY2013" tc lt 1 offset char -0.5,0
  set label 2 left at graph 0.5, char 1 "34,674" offset char 0.5,0
  ```
- Use `set macros` and define a string variable `anchor="graph 0.5, char 1"` which you use to set the anchor point of *all* labels.

  ```
  set macros
  anchor="graph 0.5, char 1"
  set label 1 at @anchor "FY2013" tc lt 1 offset char -0.5,0
  ```
- Shift all labels around a single anchor point, and parametrize the offsets from this point using two variables:

  ```
  set macros
  anchor="graph 0.5, char 1"
  ofs_x = 0.5
  dx = 20
  set label 1 right at @anchor "FY2013" tc lt 1 offset char -dx - ofs_x,0
  set label 2 left at @anchor "34,674" offset char -dx + ofs_x,0
  set label 3 right at @anchor "FY2014" tc lt 2 offset char -ofs_x,0
  set label 4 left at @anchor "16,240" offset char ofs_x,0
  set label 5 right at @anchor "FY2015" tc lt 3 offset char dx - ofs_x,0
  set label 6 left at @anchor "6,863" offset char dx + ofs_x,0

  set bmargin 3.5
  plot -x
  ```

[image]

That still isn't a fully automatic solution, but boils down to choosing appropriate values for the `anchor` and `dy` only.

Answer (score 4):

You can use enhanced text mode to overprint differently coloured labels:

```
set label 1 at 0,0 textcol rgb "red" "ONE"
set label 2 at 0,0 textcol rgb "blue" "&{ONE}TWO"
set label 3 at 0,0 textcol rgb "green" "&{ONETWO}THREE"
```

Any text that is inside the brackets in `&{SPACE}` is replaced by an empty space with the width of the text "SPACE".

In gp versions <5 you need to enable enhanced text mode first, it is by default since 5.0

update: `set xtics` works similar in principle, but you cannot set two labels a the same position, they replace each other, and the textcolor option is valid for the whole axis. So this doesn't work:

```
set xtics left ("ONE"  1) textcol rgb "red"
set xtics add ("&{ONE}TWO"  1.00001) textcol rgb "blue"
set xtics add ("&{ONETWO}THREE"  1.00002) textcol rgb "green"
```