# Gnuplot locally change label font color

Tags: colors, label, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot label for my plot

```
plot f(x) title 'Before(w)' with lines ls 1
```

In my label there is `Before(w)`. I would like the color of a letter `w` to be red. How can I do it?

I was able to find code that changes the color of the whole label (http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_4.6/textcolor.html) but it is not what I want.

Thanks.

Working example

```
set terminal postscript eps size 3.5,2.62 enhanced color \
  font 'Helvetica,20' linewidth 2
set output 'plot2.eps'

set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' linetype 1 linewidth 2 #(gnuplotting)

f(x) = exp(-x*x)
plot f(x) title 'Before(w)' with lines ls 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30467138/2604213